# NodeJS, JS how to export Promise value in a module, not the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, export

Let's say I want to export in a single JS module some value which is obtained by calling some async function. What is the mechanism to make the export wait for the result/Promise to be resolved?

As an example code snippet I put this here

```js
function go() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Success!"), 3000);
  });
}

let AS;
go().then((x) => {
  AS = x;
});
module.exports = AS;
```

This function could make any API request.
I don't want to export the entire function and call it in other module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two answers for you:

### With CommonJS (CJS)

With CommonJS (the module system you're using in that example), your best bet is to export the promise. That way, code using your module has a standard way to handle the fact that the value may not be available yet — Consuming the promise:

```
require("./your-moudule")
.then(AS => {
    // ...use `AS` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle the fact we didn't get it here...
});
```

But if you want to export the value instead, you can, it's just usually not your best approach. You'd do that by exporting an object and then updating its `AS` property:

```
function go() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Success!"), 500);
  });
}

module.exports = {AS: undefined};
go().then((x) => {
  module.exports.AS = x;
});
```

Modules using your module would have to deal with the fact that for a time, they'll be getting `undefined`. Here's code using the module above:

```
const mod = require("./promise");
const timer = setInterval(() => {
    const AS = mod.AS;
    console.log("AS = " + AS);
    if (AS) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 100);
```

If you run that, you'll see `AS = undefined` ~5 times and then `AS = Success!`.

### With JavaScript Modules (ESM)

If you can switch to using JavaScript modules instead (Node.js supports them behind a flag in v12 and without a flag in v13+, put `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`), you have a third option coming: [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await). With top-level `await` (actively being added to JavaScript engines as I write this), you can make your module execution wait for a promise to settle. So you'd do this:

```
function go() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Success!"), 500);
  });
}

const AS = await go();
export default AS; // Or `export { AS };`, but your CJS code was effectively doing `export default`
```

You can combine those lines if you want. For a default export

```
export default await go();
```

For a named export:

```
export const AS = await go();
```

Modules using your module don't have to be aware of the fact that the `AS` value comes from an asynchronous source; they aren't evaluated until your module evaluation has finished (after the promise settles). They just import as usual:

```
import AS from "./promise.js"; // If it's the default export
console.log("AS = " + AS);
```

Top-level `await` is in Node v13+ behind the `--harmony-top-level-await` flag, and will shortly be making its way into browsers.

Comment: FWIW, I cover all this in my new book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*, in Chapters 13 and 19. If you're interested, see my profile for details and links.

Comment: Thank you. Obviously the second one is much much clearer solution.

Comment: @TigranSahakyan - My pleasure! You mean top-level `await`? Yeah, it's a big improvement. :-)

Comment: Honestly, this question comes from the problem I face using Pulumi. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608754/pulumi-how-to-export-values-coming-from-async-function) it is.