# Pulumi, how to export values coming from async function?

Tags: javascript, export, pulumi

In my Pulumi project, in the index.ts file I have to call
`const awsIdentity = await aws.getCallerIdentity({ async: true });`

So for this reason I have to wrapp all my code into `async` function.
My problem is with exported variables at the end of the file.

```js
async function go() {
...
  const awsIdentity = await aws.getCallerIdentity({ async: true });
  const accountId = awsIdentity.accountId;
...
  return {
    dnsZoneName: DNSZone.name,
    BucketID: Bucket.id,
    dbHardURL: DBHost.publicDns,
    devDbURL: publicDbAddress.fqdn,
  };
}
```

I want to `export` these 4 values.
I can't understand how, but the code that follows exports( at least, `pulumi up` shows the values at the end of execution).

```js
const result = go();
export const dnsZoneName = result.then((res) => res.dnsZoneName);
```

look at [this](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/2910)

I think I can't use [top-level-await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await).

What is the clear solution ?

Comment: *"I think I can't use top-level-await."* Why not? Is there some Pulumi issue?

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who comes across this post, asynchronous entry points are now a first class citizen in Pulumi, as detailed [Here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/languages/javascript/#entrypoint)

You can have code that looks similar to this and Pulumi will automatically resolve everything for you, no need to do anything more for exporting Outputs

```
export async function go() {
...
  const awsIdentity = await aws.getCallerIdentity({ async: true });
  const accountId = awsIdentity.accountId;
...
  return {
    dnsZoneName: DNSZone.name,
    BucketID: Bucket.id,
    dbHardURL: DBHost.publicDns,
    devDbURL: publicDbAddress.fqdn,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [issue you linked](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/2910), it seems like my first suggestion in my [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62607978/157247) should work: Export a promise for each value. Based on the issue comments, it looks like Pulumi understands exported promises.

```
async function go() {
...
  const awsIdentity = await aws.getCallerIdentity({ async: true });
  const accountId = awsIdentity.accountId;
...
  return {
    dnsZoneName: DNSZone.name,
    BucketID: Bucket.id,
    dbHardURL: DBHost.publicDns,
    devDbURL: publicDbAddress.fqdn,
  };
}

const goPromise = go();
goPromise.catch(error => {
    // Report the error. Note that since we don't chain on this, it doesn't
    // prevent the exports below from rejecting (so Pulumi will see the error too,
    // which seems best).
});
export const dnsZoneName = goPromise.then(res => res.DNSZone.name);
export const BucketID = goPromise.then(res => res.Bucket.id);
export const dbHardURL = goPromise.then(res => res.DBHost.publicDns);
export const devDbURL = goPromise.then(res => res.publicDbAddress.fqdn);
```

Otherwise:

You've said you don't think you can use top-level `await`, but you haven't said why.

In case it's just that you're having trouble figuring out how to use it, you'd do it like this provided `aws.getCallerIdentity` and whatever's in the "..." of your code example provide promises:

```
const awsIdentity = await aws.getCallerIdentity({ async: true });
const accountId = awsIdentity.accountId;
// ...
export const dnsZoneName = DNSZone.name;
export const BucketID = Bucket.id;
export const dbHardURL = DBHost.publicDns;
export const devDbURL = publicDbAddress.fqdn;
```

Or if you need to export an object with those as properties as a default export:

```
const awsIdentity = await aws.getCallerIdentity({ async: true });
const accountId = awsIdentity.accountId;
// ...
export default {
    dnsZoneName: DNSZone.name
    BucketID: Bucket.id
    dbHardURL: DBHost.publicDns
    devDbURL: publicDbAddress.fqdn
};
```

Note that in both cases, the code isn't inside any function, that's at the top-level of your module.

With Node.js v13 and v14 (so far) you need the `--harmony-top-level-await` runtime flag. My guess is that it won't be behind a flag in v15 (or possibly even just a later version of v14).

Comment: `You've said you don't think you can use top-level await, but you haven't said why.`
I am not sure how to pass NodeJS arguments to Pulumi, with my current setup it gives an error. I found [this](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/3061) and it is still open.

Comment: @TigranSahakyan - Sorry, I don't see what that has to do with top-level `await`...?

Comment: I mean, I am running the script with `pulumi up` and I don't know how to pass NodeJS argument.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward way I found is to map `getCallerIdentity` to an `Output` this way

```js
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";

const account = aws.getCallerIdentity({/* async = true (by default) */});
const bucket = new aws.s3.Bucket("bucket", {
    bucket: pulumi.output(account).apply(acc => `my-bucket-${acc.accountId}`),
});
```

This way you don't have to wrap all your code in a top-level async function, which is somewhat undesirable if you need it only to get the result of that function.

Answer (score -3):

You are working with promises. Therefore, the answer can come at any time. What you should do is that when you call the function you do it with `await` to wait for the function response