# JS Nightmare not loading specific URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I have started small scraping project and stop myself on the start. While I can do the parsing part, I have problems to load the page. I've reduced the code to as little as possible and still not working for requested URL

```
// Required Libraries
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const Nightmare = require("nightmare");

const scraping = (url) => {
  url = "https://www.portaldrazeb.cz/drazba/144ex02170-20-62-rb3p1";
  // All scraping will be done here
  let nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: true });
  const nightmarePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    nightmare
      .goto(url)
      .wait("main")
      .evaluate(() => {})
      .end()
      .then((response) => {
        var json = {
          title: "",
          picture: "",
          price: "",
          starting_price: "",
          description: "",
          address: "",
          map: "",
          customer: { name: "", email: "", phone: "" },
        };
        resolve(json);
      });
  });

  return nightmarePromise.then((jsonObj) => {
    nightmare = null;
    return jsonObj;
  });
};

module.exports = {
  scraping: scraping,
};
```

While the code works reliably for whatever URL it is not working for the URL requested. The output is correct only in 30% calls, in the rest the call starts Nightmare browser, the page starts loading, then several resets occurs in a second and the browser gets closed and following error is displayed

> (node:18468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: navigation error
> at unserializeError (C:\Users\Tomas\Dropbox (Personal)\Server\ScrapReality\node_modules\nightmare\lib\ipc.js:162:13)
> at EventEmitter. (C:\Users\Tomas\Dropbox (Personal)\Server\ScrapReality\node_modules\nightmare\lib\ipc.js:89:13)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
> at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\Tomas\Dropbox (Personal)\Server\ScrapReality\node_modules\nightmare\lib\ipc.js:49:10)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at emit (internal/child_process.js:876:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
> (node:18468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)

Comment: You are exporting a promise. See the first answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607868/nodejs-js-how-to-export-promise-value-in-a-module-not-the-function/62607978#62607978) if that is really your intent.

Comment: Tried to experiment with that, but the resets while loading page persists. Could this be only problem for particular URL while other URLs behave normal?

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: It's in the code: https://www.portaldrazeb.cz/drazba/144ex02170-20-62-rb3p1

Comment: Whoops! - anyway, there is no evidence of any error handling here. Add a `.catch()` clause so you can review the reason for the rejection (assuming nightmare provides a descriptive reason) and that returns an empty object. That will resolve the unhandledPromiseRejection. Most likely, that will then expose a different error that is occurring.