# export awaited value as ESM module

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, export, es6-modules

I just noticed, that the following is working in node 14.17.3:

a.js:

```
console.log("a.js executes")
async function wait(){
    console.log('wait runs')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{resolve("foo")},3000)
    })
}
export default await wait()
```

b.js:

```
import data from './a.js'
console.log("b.js executes")

export default function test(){
    console.log("b.js: imported from a.js:",data)
}
```

c.js:

```
import data from './a.js'
console.log("c.js executes")

export default function test(){
    console.log("c.js: imported from a.js:",data)
}
```

d.js:

```
import test_b from './b.js'
import test_c from './c.js'

test_b()
test_c()
```

When i run `d.js` i get the following output, while there is a 3 second delay between the second and the third line:

```
a.js executes
wait runs
b.js executes
c.js executes
b.js: imported from a.js foo
c.js: imported from a.js: foo
```

This is exactly what i want, but i don't understand why this works.
The module loader seems to actually wait for the async `wait` function to resolve, before executing `b.js` and `c.js` and importing the resolved value into the modules.

I would bet, that this did not work a couple of years ago.

Could someone tell me what this feature is called? Is it a feature of ES itself, or of the module loader system of node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called top-level `await`. There is a clear explanation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62607978/16602311), in the second option.

Comment: Thank you. This is also interesting: https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221